# пожалуйста помогите, clearTimeout не работает

Tags: javascript, cleartimeout

Код: https://pastebin.com/raw/yQdHdEMW

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         autoplayerludwigos
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description 
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
var adminsusers = [];
var t = 0;
var n;
var u;
var v;
var JSNMPB = [];
var JSNMPBcurrentsong;
    MPP.client.on("a", function (msg) {
    a = msg.a.split(' ');
    b = a[0];
    input = msg.a.substring(b.length).trim(); // <--- for if I make more commands :D
 var msgArr = msg.a.split(' ');
        if ((adminsusers.indexOf(msg.p._id) > - 1) || (msg.p._id==MPP.client.getOwnParticipant()._id)){ if (msgArr[0] == '/js' ) { try { MPP.chat.send("> "+ input);MPP.chat.send('< '+JSON.stringify(eval(msg.a.substr(msgArr[0].length).trim()))); } catch (error) { MPP.chat.send('ⓧ '+error); } } }
        if (b == "/play" || b =="/p") {
       if (!input) { MPP.chat.send("You don't choose song");} if (input == "0") { 
       if (t == 0) {                            
            n=-1;
            u=300;                                  
            v=299;         MPP.chat.send("Reading file. Name: Fur elise. [00:50]");
     JSNMPBcurrentsong = /*setInterval(function () {*/MPP.press("e4",1);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);           
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs2",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs3",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs2",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {},                       t++ * 50); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs2",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs3",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs2",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c2",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("g2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("g3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("f4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("g1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("g2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("f3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * v); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * v); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * v); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * v); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * v); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e5",1);},     t++ * v); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs2",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs3",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("ds4",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("d4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e1",1);},     n * u);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e2",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("gs2",1);},    t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("e3",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("c4",1);},     t++ * u); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("b3",1);},     t++ * u + 100); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a3",1);},     t++ * u + 300); n++;
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a1",1);},     n * u + 300);
setTimeout(function () {MPP.press("a2",1);},     n * u + 300);;//}, 1000);;
//setTimeout(function () {clearInterval(JSNMPBcurrentsong);}, 50000);               
t = 0;    
                       }}}
if (b == "/stop") {clearTimeout(JSNMPBcurrentsong);}
    });
```

Код для сайта multiplayerpiano.com

Проблема: При вводе в чат комманду /p 0, песня "fur elise" играет, но при вводе /stop, песня не останавливается.

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: clearTimeoutl(JSNMPBcurrentsong);

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ошибка: Кажется ваше сообщение содержит код...

Comment: при вводе /p 0 в чат на сайте multiplayerpiano.com, на пианино автоматически играет песня fur elise, а при вводе /stop она всё равно играет. Команда /stop должна работать.

Comment: все способы испробовал. Эти setTimeout'ы поместил в setInterval и заменил clearTimeout(JSNMPBcurrentsong);на clearInterval(JSNMPBcurrentsong); но песня не останавливается

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: код слишком длинный

Comment: Сокращайте. Выкиньте всё, что не относится непосредственно к проблеме.

Comment: вот так? setTimeout(mycode,1000);

Comment: я конечно не вдаюсь в логику всего происходящего и зачем стооооооооолько таймаутов но.... ты же почти всё можешь вызывать в цикле.. при этом `setTimeout` возвращает `timerId`. Соответственно для большинства ты можешь пробежаться в цикле и положить все идентификаторы в массив.... А потом, когда они не нужны пробежаться по циклу с идентификаторами и сделать `clearInterval` для каждого

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что надо все вложенные `setTimeout` тоже отменять.

Comment: Как отменять??? Убирать все setTimeout'ы??

Comment: @LGPvS, сложи все значения `setTimeout(...)` в массив и для каждого из них вызови `clearTimeout`

Comment: как сложить и как вызвать?

Comment: это долго делать

Comment: @LGPvS, т. е. если это долго делать, то это должен сделать кто-то за тебя? Нет, не хочу.

Comment: как вызвать для каждого clearTimeout?

Comment: почему же clearTimeout не работает?

Comment: @LGPvS, ты позвал 200 не знакомых между собой людей на вечеринку. А потом одному из них сказал что она отменяется. Почему оставшиеся 199 должны не прийти?

Comment: потому что только ему сказал